# What username to use for my own domain on a resume?

Tags: resume

I've been reading around, but I want to see what would employers or what does the general prefer to use or see for their e-mail address?

I have my own domain. Some say to do:

resume@johndoe.com

And I've also read:
johndoe@johndoe.com

Which I think is really repetitive? There are other variations of this.

What would be the best approach to using your own domain's email address?

Answer (score 6):

contact@johndoe.com would be the best, I think.  After all, you're not having them email your resume (unless you set up some sort of Daemon to automatically reply to any emails to that domain with a copy of your resume).  I would avoid using things such as me@johndoe.com (too short and unprofessional) or webmaster@johndoe.com (again, fairly unprofessional sounding).

Comment: I'm still reading around, jd@johndoe.com, would be bad? So I should try to avoid short?

Comment: i would say, avoid short and unprofessional.  it might just be me, but a 2-letter email address (domains don't count) just look...odd.

Comment: Maybe johndoe@johndoe.com or jdoe@johndoe.com would have to suffice. contact@johndoe.com seems too business like.

Are there any ones you use yourself?

Comment: personally, i don't realy like the whole 'personal domain' thing as much, mostly because it just makes things like this awkward.  i use one of my 6 gmail accounts for any professional correspondance, with the format LastnameFirstname@gmail.com

Comment: Right now, I am using a gmail one too. I use Full last name, first letter of first name, and abbreviated middle.
John Micheal Angelo Doe
Doejma@gmail.com, Since I do have my own domain name, I was thinking, why not~kind of scenario.

Answer (score 4):

I'd go with john@johndoe.com, or if that seems too informal then john.doe@johndoe.com.

In general it's kind of a status symbol to a lot of people to have a first name only email, for example bill@microsoft.com would be kind of special.

As some who reviews resumes I'd find resume@johndoe.com to be kind of confusing.  Why would I email your resume, I'm looking right at it!

Answer (score 0):

I thnk any email address is OK as long as it doesn't sound unprofessinal. Therefore it should not:

- Include swear words
- Include sexual references
- Sound hateful  (john@kukluxklan.org)
- Sound silly or immature (gigglesnort@jackass.com)
- Sound religious or political

If your name falls into one of these categories naturally, consider long and hard as to whether to use it or at least how to use it in your personal email.

Comment: I like this answer and want to upvote it, however it doesn't really answer the question asked about which email address is the most professional to use if you have your own domain name.

Comment: That far I know, but I'm having trouble deciding the front part. I dislike the idea of repetition, but I want something as professional as possible, yet very simple so they remember.